# How can I connect to Shapeways.com's API more than once?

Tags: python, api, flask

I'm developing a Python web app and using the Flask framework to communicate with Shapeways.com's API. I'm using a [module provided by Shapeways](https://github.com/Shapeways/python-shapeways) to connect. I'm able to authenticate (the API uses OAuth v1) using the following steps from [the module's docs](http://python-shapeways.readthedocs.org/en/latest/client.html):

1. Create a client
2. Connect to API and get request token and authentication url
3. Send user to authentication url
4. Verify callback from authentication url

I can then upload 3D models and read data from existing models in the user's account.

However if I refresh the page after connecting, I'm no longer able to obtain a url from the module's `connect()` method. I have to restart the script (or restart Apache when using mod_wsgi) before I can obtain a new URL. Here's a stripped-down example:

```
from flask import Flask, request, redirect
from urllib.parse import urlencode
import urllib.parse
from shapeways.client import Client

consumer_key = [my app's key]
consumer_secret = [my app's secret]
callback_url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/callback"
client = Client(consumer_key, consumer_secret, callback_url)

app = Flask(__name__)

app.debug = True
app.secret_key = "FZ\x96\xf0\x94\xa0:\xe2\x9a&\x88\xc3\x1c\xdf\xfc\x83`gw.\xab\x83\xf1d"

@app.route("/")
def root():
    url = client.connect()
    return redirect(url, code=302)

@app.route("/callback")
def callback():
    oauth_token = request.args.get("oauth_token", 0, type=str)
    oauth_verifier = request.args.get("oauth_verifier", 0, type=str)
    client.verify(oauth_token, oauth_verifier)
    info = client.get_api_info()
    return str(info)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The first time I load the page, `connect()` obtains a request token and URL from the API and redirects me to Shapeways.com, where I log in and give permission. That page then redirects to the callback URL, where verification takes place.

If I reload the page, `client.connect()` returns `None`. The same thing happens if I try to access the page from another browser.

Am I using the API (or Flask) incorrectly? What should I change to prevent the app from only allowing a single user to log in? What else could I try to debug this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Shapeways `Client` builds a single client, which you are doing the OAuth dance for. So you shouldn't expect new clients to be built every single time you "connect", a single client has already been established and verified, and Shapeways expects you to reuse that client to communicate with their API.

Comment: Ahhh... sounds promising. Thanks. I'll try that this evening and mark accepted if it does the trick.